# How to get random value from function

Tags: python

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,name,hitpoint,damage,sp):
        self.name=name
        self.hitpoint=hitpoint
        self.damage=damage
        self.sp=sp
        
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,name,hitpoint,damage):
        self.name=name
        self.hitpoint=hitpoint
        self.damage=damage   
        
hero=Hero("mostafa", 100, 20 , 40)
enemy=Enemy("vice-T", 210, 30 )
  
def hero_attack():
    enemy.hitpoint=enemy.hitpoint-hero.damage
              
    if enemy.hitpoint>=0:
        print (enemy.name," is still alive", enemy.name, "'s life is now ", enemy.hitpoint)
    else:
        print (enemy.name," is dead congrats you win ")

def enemy_attack():
    hero.hitpoint=hero.hitpoint-enemy.damage           
       
    if hero.hitpoint>=0:
        print (hero.name," is still alive", hero.name, "'s life is now ", hero.hitpoint)
        
    else:
        print (hero.name," is dead Enemy Win ")


     enemy_attack()
     hero_attack()
```

here i want to random attack between enemy_attack() and hero_attack() function. suppose i will declare a variable called attack which gives me either enemy_attack() or hero_attack(). plz help

Comment: Use python randoms

Comment: Generate a random number. Then use that random number in a conditional using a modulus check `if someVal % 2 = 0: //do this else: //do this`

Answer (score 0):

Use random module of python that choose a random value. Just Try below code:

```
import random
enemy_attack() if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else hero_attack()
```